# IE6 and addClass() in Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-6

This doesn't seem to work in Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".navlist li").each(function() {
        var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");


        if ($(this).find("a").attr("href") == window.location.pathname) {
           $(this).attr("class", "active"); 
        }
    });

});
```

in my html

```
<div id="main-navigation">
                <ul class="navlist">   
                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/home.aspx")%>">home</a></li>                 
                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/sample-templates/view-list.aspx")%>">manage sample templates</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/fractional-templates/manage.aspx")%>">manage fractional templates</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/faq.aspx")%>">faq</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

in my css

```
.navlist li.active a
{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #369;
    text-decoration: none;  
}
```

Any suggestions?

I debugged the js and the problem is that the class is not being added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was css

it should be

```
.navlist .active a:link, .active a:visited, .active a:visited, .active a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #369;
    text-decoration: none;  
}
```

instead of

```
.navlist li.active a
{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #369;
    text-decoration: none;  
}
```

Comment: :-) funny that you spent that much time looking in the wrong direction

Comment: granted, i did post my css here - so people were invited to look and point it out:)

Answer (score 1):

Does the first selector work? Have you tried debugging it? Say, add some `alert("i am here")` before `var href=...` If yes, are you sure that the comparison `$(this).find("a").attr("href") == window.location.pathname` is ever true?

Maybe you can try a "smarter" jQuery select, where you first match all `A` elements that have the required url and then just add the classname:

```
$(".navlist li a[href='" + window.location.pathname +"']").parent().attr("class", "active");
```

EDIT: There may be a problem with naming. Since "class" is a reserved word, you have to use "className" attribute! so, my code becomes:

```
$(".navlist li a[href='" + window.location.pathname +"']").parent().attr("className", "active");
```

or even better:

```
$(".navlist li a[href='" + window.location.pathname +"']").parent().addClass("active");
```

Comment: thanks, yes, i verified that the comparison holds true when it should. the code works on IE7 but not on IE6.

Comment: i just tried your code and it again works on IE7 and not IE6.

Comment: So you mean that it actually enters the `if(..)` body even in IE6, but never sets the class attribute. What if you substitute the `.attr("class", "active")` with `.addClass("active")`?

Comment: that's exactly it - it enters the if statement, but won't add the class. I tried both addClass and the attr methods, neither works. I googled it and apparently CSS2 is not supported in IE6...I am not really a browser expert, so I am not sure if this is the reason. But my code works perfectly in FF and IE7, just not IE6.

Comment: try setting both `class` and `className` attributes. This should fix IE6 (see comments of this article: http://woork.blogspot.com/2008/01/change-class-attribute-using-javascript.html )

Comment: jQuery `attr` changes the name `class` to the proper JavaScript property name `className` for you.

Comment: Is the attribute set, if you find it in the DOM, using developer toolbar (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en)?

Comment: document.getElementById("idElement").setAttribute("className", "myClass");
document.getElementById("idElement").setAttribute("class", "myClass");

don't work either.

Comment: try `document.getElementById("idElement").className="myClass"`. Sorry for throwing unvalidated ideas at you, but I don't have IE6 where I could test them :-)

Comment: thanks:) it's ok. I think at the end I just might tell users to upgrade. It's an intranet site. But it will drive me nuts meanwhile.

Comment: can't you just do it on the server side? Like, checking if the resolved URL matches the `Page.URL` (don't know what language that is)

Comment: interesting twist - i looked at the dev tool bar and the class does get loaded. so the issue must be with my css

Comment: try putting a `<li class="active">` in your HTML code, without any jquery - does it show anything?

Comment: just tried your advice - bypassing the jquery now, working with old js, css and html....background color still won't show up in IE6

Answer (score 0):

Comparing `attr('href')` against `location.pathname` isn't so reliable. `attr()` reads JavaScript properties, not HTML attributes; the JavaScript property for `href` is normally a resolved absolute URI. jQuery tries to work around some of the problems with that difference, but I don't know that it's always successful.

What would be more reliable would be remember that an HTMLAnchorElement object also works as a Location object, so you can compare them pathnames directly:

```
if (this.hostname===location.hostname && this.pathname===location.pathname)
```

This now checks that it's an internal link with the same path as the current page. It ignores any trailing `?query` or `#hash` parts.

```
$(this).attr("class", "active");
```

The `addClass` you mention in the title is definitely a better way of saying that.

This definitely should work in IE6. What *won't* work in IE6, which might be tripping you up, is that though you can have an element with multiple classes, you can't have a CSS selector with multiple class requirements on the same element, eg.:

```
a.mylink.active { ... }
```

this will incorrectly require only the `active` class in IE6. Many other selectors aren't supported in IE6 either, for example the `>` child selector:

```
div.thing > a.action { ... }
```

will never match in IE6.

Comment: Thanks, pathname comparison works, so that's not a problem. addClass() function doesn't work either ....please read my comments reggarding both above. I am also not using 2 classes either - look @ my code. Any other ideas?

Comment: actually, `$this` does refer to a LI element, since it calls each() on a collection of list elements.

Comment: I've just tried the example and it works fine for me in IE6. Whatever the problem is, it's not in the code above. I still suspect something IE6 can't parse in the stylesheet. Can we see a test page that breaks for you?